# Refactoring method reduce cognitive complexity for switch case

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, spring-boot, jackson

Hello I am having difficulty to reduce cognitive complexity is there any way to reduce ?
any help would be appreciated. Because of Sonarlint I am not able to pass my code

Thank you

```
private void addSth(List<Integer> myStatus, List<String> myId, String taskOwner, StringBuilder queryStatement, List<Object> args) {
        
        if (null != myStatus&& myStatus.size >0) {
             queryStatement.append("and (");
        for(int i = 1; i <= status.size(); i++) {
          int status = myStatus.get(i-1);
    
           switch (status) {
            case 1:
             StringBuilder potSth = new StringBuilder();
             if (null != myId && myId.size() > 0) {
             pothSth.append("(");
    
           for (int j=1; j <= myId.size(); j++) 
               pothSth.append(" ? ");
          if (j < myId.size()) 
              pothSth.append(", ")
                
           
           pothSth.append(")");
             
          
          queryStatement.append("sth");
          queryStatement.append(pothSth);
         queryStatement.append(")\n");

         args.add(1);
        
        for (String pOwner : ownerId) {
          args.add(pOwner);
          
     break;

     case 2:
     case 3:
         queryStatement.append("or ");
       args.add(status);
       args.add(taskOwner);
     

  if (i < myStatus.size ) {
  queryStatement.append("or ");
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include all of your code and could you also format your code so it's easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonarlint measures cognitive complexity on the basis of three factors:

> 1. Ignore structures that allow multiple statements to be readably shorthanded into one.
> 2. Increment (add one) for each break in the linear flow of the code.
> 3. Increment when flow-breaking structures are nested.

Source: [Cognitive Complexity White Paper](https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf) page 4

I would recommend breaking the `addSth` method down into several smaller methods, perhaps for handling the status, appending to `pothSth` and appending to `queryStatement`.

Also it appears to be missing some curly braces at the end so, so I'm not totally sure what this code is doing. Like Jonny said, some context and formatting would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Curly brackets in the code is right but, I could not put it here, can you also write how can ı breaking my method into smaller methods

Comment: Since there aren't any closing braces I'm not sure what is nested into what, but something along the lines of
`private void addSth(...args...) {
     appendAndIfValidStatus(queryStatement)
     ...
     appendCharBasedOnStatus(pothSth)
     ...
     addPOwner(args, pOwner)
    ...
}`

(Apologies for the weird formatting, mini-Markdown is new to me)